# Laravel Filesystem interface - get Path as output

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bit of code like this:

`Storage::disk('local')->put('a/b/c.TXT', $contents);`

I'm fairly sure that the `Storage::disk('local')` bit of code outputs a Filesystem object: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html
but I could be wrong about that

Now, I know that that code writes the contents to a file in `/laravel_root/storage/app/a/b/c.TXT`

What I want is a method like this: `Storage::disk('local')->getPath('a/b/c.TXT')` that outputs the full path: `/laravel_root/storage/app/a/b/c.TXT`. I'm looking through the docs but I can't find such a method. The only lead I have is that maybe, MAYBE `->dirname` will give me `/laravel_root/storage/app/a/b` but I'm not even sure about that!

Comment: Not this? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-paths

Comment: @user3532758 that might be exactly what i'm looking for. I'll try it

Comment: @user3532758 that's it. You want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the absolute path of the file; `Storage::path()` gives just that.

Documentation Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-paths